# Weird Git issue: stuck at 100% completion at checkout

Tags: git

When I checkout any branch from a remote repo of my employer it reaches 100% completion at files update and gets stuck. The dialog just keeps hanging there without any errors for literal hours. (see attached pic). The same thing happens when I try to clone the repository.

Info:

- I use HTTPS auth
- I tried branching/cloning from GitHub test repository, everything worked just fine.
- I use Git Extensions, but also tried Git UI with the same result.
- Windows 10, i9, 32 Gb RAM, 1TB SSD
- This only happens on my new work PC, I had no problems on my old personal PC with far worse specs. Used the same software. None of my colleagues run into this issue.
- I run it with admin privileges, tried several times, restarted PC, etc.
- Repo in question is pretty large (~125GB).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default?  Those can interfere with Git in various ways, including preventing files from being opened, which could cause this problem.

Comment: Yes, there is an antivirus software, ESET. Not sure if I can disable it (since it's employer's PC), but I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling AV did not help. However, switching auth from https to SSH did resolve the problem.

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer to your problem.